# Kerberos net ads join doesn't respond

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to join Active Directory in Xubuntu 16.04 in a enterprise business enviroment so I'll change the name of my REALM by MY.EXAMPLE.CORP. My issue is: when I run

```
net ads join -U Administrator
```

it asks me the password for the AD administrator account, I put the password but it stills there, it doesn't give an error or success message. Just still there. The terminal just hanged in there

I tried the `kinit` and `klist` commands and the result is:

```
Tickect cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: Administrator@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP

Valid starting      Expires         Service principal
11/11/16 09:58:40   11/11/16 19:58:40   krbgt/MY.EXAMPLE.CORP@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP
    renew until   12/11/16 09:58:34
```

These are the changes that I've done in every file. krb5.conf, smb.conf, nsswitch.conf

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.CORP

....

[realms]
DOMAIN = {
        kdc = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        kdc = SERVER02.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        admin_server = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP SERVER.MY.DOMAIN.CORP
        default_domain = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    }

....


[domain_realm]
    SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    SERVER02.MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    .MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    MY.DOMAIN.CORP = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
    realm = MY.DOMAIN.CORP
    security = ADS
    encrypt passwords = yes
    password server = SERVER01.MY.DOMAIN.CORP SERVER02.MYDOMAIN.CORP
    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = true
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    winbind use default domain = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    winbind offline logon = yes
```

nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat
```